# Why EF-core code first makes DateTime2 instead of DateTime?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Im very new in EF-core code first, I want to be a variable in the form of a datetime,but its Datetime2. how can I fix it?

This is EF core , code first Approach and sql server 2017

```
public class MB_Message
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MessageID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? expireDateTime { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public bool IsForceLastSend { get; set; }
    public DateTime MessageDateTime { get; set; }
    public bool ReadOnce { get; set; }
    public string ExeCode { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MB_Queue")]
    public int QueueCode { get; set; }
    public int? UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MB_MessageBody")]
    public int BodyID { get; set; }
    public bool Enable { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In OnModelCreating method of your dbcontext add following:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.Entity<MB_Message>()
            .Property(x=> x.MessageDateTime )
            .HasColumnType("datetime");
    }
```

Comment: I tried it, but that's not what I want. It only produces date. If I put datetime instead of the date, it will be datetime2 again

Comment: In dbcontext and OnModelCreating method add this:                                                       `builder.Entity<MB_Message>()
                .Property(f => f.MessageDateTime )
                .HasColumnType("datetime");`

Answer (score 1):

To answer the "Why?"; because `datetime` is an old SQL Server specific data type that [Microsoft recommend you avoid now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Maybe you need it to join on existing tables, but for new work `datetime` is not advised.

In comparison to `datetime2(3)`, datetime is:

- incompatible with other SQL systems so will need converting
- takes up 1 more byte of data per row (duplicated for every index and RAM every time it's read)
- offers no option for precision

Added to that, you probably want `datetime2(0)` in most cases, which is 2 bytes less than a datetime.